# Websocket over SSL using play framework / javascript

Tags: websocket, playframework-2.0

Using play framework, I can easily create WebSockets using the below line of code....
var chatSocket = new WS("@routes.Application.chat(username).webSocketURL(request)")

Since WebSocket may not work well with some of the old proxies, it is suggested to use SSL as per http://www.websocket.org/echo.html. How do I change the above line of code to create WebSocket using SSL? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,

Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

True adding the true parameter to the webSocketURL call.  Looking at the source, it looks like it would work.

```
var chatSocket = new WS("@routes.Application.chat(username).webSocketURL(request, true)")
```

(source is [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Call.java))